# AWS - DNS fails to Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've been scouring online and following guidance to the letter but hitting an issue getting a successful DNS resolution, I hope you can help.

I have an EC2 instance hosting a basic web app, with an Elastic IP attached to that instance. Navigating to the Elastic IP is successful and I can access the app (browsing to `http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx`).

I've registered a domain through Route 53 and that is displaying. I've created a hosted zone - initially the Name Servers didn't match the domain registration and a Test Record failed. I've changed the NS details to match that of the Registered Domain and the Test Record now succeeds.

I've added a record to the Hosted Zone (Record type A, I've verified the value is the Elastic IP, TTL 300 on Simple Routing). This results in a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error when trying to navigate to the address.

I can't think of what other information to provide. Annoyingly I followed the same steps previously and it worked first time but I tore the instance down for intense debugging!

Security Group (Inbound):

```
sgr-08c70629989159bef   IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   –
sgr-07bfd9815f5b49e27   IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   –
sgr-076d93d22a441005c   IPv4    SSH TCP 22  109.150.228.140/32
```

Security Group (Outbound):

```
sgr-049ed17ff4caa8935   IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   –
sgr-0fa4371f7df144f16   IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   –
sgr-028599127e1b9375d   IPv4    All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   –
```

I have one public subnet for which the NACLs are:

```
Inbound:
100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Deny

Outbound: 
100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Deny
```

Thanks!

Comment: A DNS name resolution error is an issue with DNS only. You probably just need to clear your local DNS cache. The security group rules and NACLs are completely irrelevant for this issue.

Comment: I've resolved this. For anyone else having the same issue - correct the Name Servers in your Registered Domain, rather than in your Hosted Zone.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this. For anyone else having the same issue - correct the Name Servers in your Registered Domain, rather than in your Hosted Zone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).